# Difference between null? and empty? in Scheme

Tags: scheme

Berkeley's "CS 61A Lecture 8: UI Recursion and Iteration III" says that
null? checks if the list is empty and empty? checks if the list is empty or the word is empty? The lecturer also goes on to say (null? empty) will return false. But DrScheme doesnt mind at all.

What is the difference between null? and empty? in Scheme?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No difference (in my favorite dialect -- `empty?` is not in the standard, and it's too long since I used any different dialect;)...!  Quoting [PLT scheme docs](http://docs.plt-scheme.org/reference/pairs.html):

```
(null? v) → boolean?
  v : any/c

Returns #t if v is the empty list, #f otherwise.
```

and

```
(empty? v) → boolean?
  v : any/c

The same as (null? v).
```

Comment: Is empty defined only in PLTScheme?

Comment: It's not in the standard, AFAIK, and it's been far too long since I used any other dialect - I'd better edit the answer to hint at that!-)

Comment: PLT (or DRScheme but that's the same bundle;-).

Comment: This answer is almost a decade old, but just wanted to say mit-scheme only recognizes `null?`

Answer (score 4):

Neither R5RS nor R6RS defines `empty?` as a predicate, and both define `null?` as follows:

> Returns `#t` if *obj* is the empty list, otherwise returns `#f`.

Answer (score 2):

you can 
        (define empty? null?)
        (define empty '())

Answer (score 0):

empty? is specific to PLT Scheme; it is the same as null?.